# Remotely accessible android emulator

Tags: android, virtual-machine, remote-access, android-virtual-device

I am given a scenario "let's say I am an android developer and I want to test my applications on an emulator, but I don't have the required resources available to create an emulator right away, so I am given an option to test my application remotely on an android emulator which has been deployed somewhere on the web"

given this situation I want to make a way to remotely access my emulator from various devices, so how will my approach be? How to make an emulator for remote access, let's assume for time being I have my emulator up and running on my host pc and my friend should be able to access my emulator over the web to test his application. How to make this possible?

what are the different ways I can tackle this situation ?

I read the artcle on doing the same on Google Cloud Platform but it requires card details. I would not like to go with that approach please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is with [STF](https://github.com/DeviceFarmer/stf) but a tunnel to your adb instance will also work